# Make the title of a web page show javascript variable

Tags: javascript, html, web, title

Hey guys I was wondering how I could make the title of my website display the value of a javascript variable.  I have a variable -  currentversion and I want that number its equal to to be displayed in the title as if it were inside the `<title></title>` tags. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you do *any* research before asking this question?

Comment: LOL all the answers are the same: `document.title = xyz;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `document.title`:

```
document.title = currentversion;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title

Answer (score 3):

```
window.document.title = "New Title" // or currentversion.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Have you tried using the `document.title` property?</strike>

Use the `document.title` property.

Comment: is this an answer or a question?

Comment: my apologies to the grammar police.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I can't believe we are nitpicking over this.

Comment: @missingno its not nitpicking or grammar...  its about using the site properly... answers should not be probing for more info, that is what comments are for.  this site is as high quality as it is because of (nitpicky) community moderation.

Comment: @jondavidjohn I think we can make an exception in this case since the OP obviously did not even try googling this.

Comment: @puk if its a poor question flag or vote to close it... if you have an opinion or question about the question leave a comment...

Comment: @jondavidjohn it's in that purgatory state of SO questions where it's not quite worthy of outright deletion, but not SO material either. It is, however, ridicule worthy (I am of course talking [tongue in cheek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek))

Answer (score 2):

```
document.title = "This is your current version:" + currentversion;
```

Just treat it like any other string